# How to inherit mathematical operations?

Tags: python

For a group of objects that are number like (called an ordered field) you only need the following things:

- Addition
- Multiplication
- Negation
- Reciprocal
- LessThanEqual

And the rest (like subtraction and equality) follow. Obvioulsy, I will also need to add things like `__init__` and `__str__`, but what type of object can I inherit from that will supply the other operators? Some other operators that I wish would be inferred from the above include:

- Subtraction
- Division
- Absolute Value
- All other comparison operators
- Etc...

Comment: what are you talking about? what do you exactly want to achieve? where does what you said come from?

Comment: He wants an ABC that defines all the numeric special methods not in his list, by using those that are.

Comment: You'll want to implement all of these: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#numeric

Comment: @jterrace you should make it an answer then

Comment: @zmo thanks, I just did

Comment: Isn't it simple enough to write a base class that defines the dependent operators by calling the core operators? And let implementers provide just the core operators for each specific class?

Comment: @David: I think the question is asking whether such a base class *already exists*.

Comment: Doesn't look like such an ABC exists. Please post a self-answer if you decide to roll your own.

Comment: I am thinking about it.

Comment: (Like I could have detect which methods you have, and then determine how to fill in the others.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [numbers](http://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers) module. It has abstract base classes for numeric types.

Also take a look at the list of magic methods related to numerical types:
http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#numeric

Comment: What exactly are we supposed to do with this numbers module? Do you have any details? Which class do we inherit from?

Comment: I did. I do not see how it related to the question. None of those classes can be an ABC for a field as I understand it. You should explain which ABC applies here, and how it would be used. Can you please do that.

Answer (score 2):

While not a complete answer, for comparisons, there is [`functools.total_ordering`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering).

Comment: Though `<=` alone isn't enough, one also needs `==`.

Comment: @delnan: Right, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: I did not expect this, but I put in __le__ and __eq__, and it put in all the other operations automatically, without functools.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override operators for that.

The complete method is well documented here: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: I do know about them. The point is for me not having to do this.